# Logic behind URLs ending with a slash "/"

Tags: url

I wanted to know about URLs that do/do not end with a slash at the end. For example `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/`.

I know that both of them lead to the same web document but does it lead to the same performance while typing any of these URL in the browser? Is it true that not typing slash at the end of the URL leads to a redirect? Also does it have an extra effect on the server? If so, how? And what exactly is the significance of slash at the end? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google is your buddy: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/why-urls-end-in-slash.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the root of a site, there is no difference: `http://www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com/` have the exact same effect.

On the other hand, there is a difference between `http://www.example.com/foo` and `http://www.example.com/foo/`: the first requests path `/foo`, while the latter requests path `/foo/`.  If `/foo` is a directory, most web servers will return a redirect to `/foo/` for the first URL, which will cause an extra round-trip.

Comment: Oh! I thought URLs are normalized at the browser level...and might not affect the server performance...?

Comment: @hnvasa no, the browser doesn't know whether /foo is a directory or a file that you wish to download.  Only the server can make that decision.

Answer (score 0):

The '/' at the end is because we have to go the root of that address. We can do without the slash these days because the browser's automatically thinks you are going there the same way we can go without mentioning port 80.

PS- My first answer so go easy on me :P